# Skipping formatting certain values in python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe. My column `Date-Time` contains dates and times. Some are formatted as dates and some were typed in as strings.
Using python I want to skip cells that are of type `str` and apply this function to the rest:

```
df['Date-Time'] = df['Date-Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```py
df['Date-Time'] = df['Date-Time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') if isinstance(x, datetime.date) else x)
```

This will format all date values and keep the others as they are